# How can I tail a log file with the date appended to its name?

Tags: shell, tail, flume

I am trying to use tail -f command on a file whose name changes daily i.e. the current date is appended to its name. I tried doing this :

```
CURRENTDATE=$(date +%Y%m%d.log)

tail -F $CURRENTDATE
```

but it tails the files with the `CURRENTDATE` set to the time when the script was executed. Is there any way the tail command can automatically switch to the new file when the date changes ? I cannot use crontab here to execute this command every day. Basically I am using this with Flume NG exec source.

I would really appreciate some help on this.

Comment: What date do you want to use? The modification date of the file? The most recent file in a directory? You could get the most recent file using `ls -tr *.log | tail -n1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way the tail command itself can automatically switch to the new file with a different name when the date changes. Thus, you have to kill the old tail and start a new one in due time.

```
while
    tail -F `date +%Y%m%d.log`& sleep $(expr `date +%s -d'day 0'` - `date +%s`)
do  kill $!
done
```

Answer (score 1):

To tail the most recent `.log` file in a directory:

```
LASTFILE=$(ls -t *.log | head -1)

tail -F $LASTFILE
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using flume-ng exec tailing rotated log files too.
Here's my solution:

```
originAgent.sources.originSource2.type = exec                                                                                                                                             
originAgent.sources.originSource2.command = locktail_rotate.sh /path/to/test.DATE_ROTATE.log 'date +"%Y%m%d"'
```

And you can checkout locktail_rotate.sh from [here](https://github.com/kylelin/locktail/blob/master/locktail_rotate.sh).